# View layout changes when setting the image of a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

I have a layout which is made using autolayout and stack views. The screen contains couple of text input fields and a button.

I have a tiny button which serves as the Accept terms and conditions, for which I need to set two images based on whether the image is selected or in default state. The problem is, when I set the image on the button, the other stack-views and rest of the layout moves/gets distorted. The button has a (width, height) of (22,22).

Without setting Image on Button :
[image: Without setting Image on Button]

After setting Image on Button :
[image: After setting Image on Button]

My constraints are as follows: 
[image]

View hierarchy as follows:
[image]

Constraints on the button:
[image]

My question is, how do I set the image on the button, without changing the styling of other sections of the UIView.

Comment: have you given the fix width and height to the tiny button?

Comment: just upload the screenshots in both the scenarios. Distorted and okay one.

Comment: Yes, I have set fixed width/height. Uploaded the images as asked.

Comment: are you using relative leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: your font size is also increased after setting the image

Comment: need to see your view hierarchy. The problem is with the constraints

Comment: Added the images which show the constraints and view hierarchy

Comment: do one thing try to remove the constraint **Align center x to stack view** and once again check the output in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting fixed height and width to Button.

Comment: Yes, i have set the fixed height/width on the button. I have added the images for better clarity on the question.